# Using Linq to merge to List

Tags: linq, merge, combinations

I have the code like this.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     public string NickName { get; set; }
}

var table1 = new List<Employee>() {
                new Employee(){ ID=1, Name="A"},
                new Employee(){ ID=2, Name="B"},
                new Employee(){ ID=3, Name="C"},
                new Employee(){ ID=5, Name="E"},
            };
var table2 = new List<Employee>() {
                new Employee(){ ID=1, NickName="NickA"},
                new Employee(){ ID=2, NickName="NickB"},
                new Employee(){ ID=3, NickName="NickC"},
                new Employee(){ ID=4, NickName="NickD"}
            };
```

I want to merge two lists above to something like this:

```
{ID=1, Name="A", NickName="NickA"}
{ID=2, Name="B", NickName="NickB"}
{ID=3, Name="C", NickName="NickC"}
{ID=4, Name=null, NickName="NickD"}
{ID=5, Name="E", NickName=null}
```

How can I do it using LinQ. Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `ID`, and pick the "first of" value for each field, like this:

```
var res = table1.Concat(table2).GroupBy(e => e.ID)
    .Select(g => new Employee {
        ID = g.Key
    ,   Name = g.Select(e => e.Name).FirstOrDefault(s => s != null)
    ,   NickName = g.Select(e => NickName).FirstOrDefault(s => s != null)
    });
```

Note that if you take this approach it does not matter from what table the `Name` or the `NickName` comes: you could mix assignments in your lists, and let LINQ group them back for you.

Comment: what about ``Concat``??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad My answer already uses `Concat` as the first step.

Comment: Thanks for very quickly answer @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var results = table1.Select(t1 => {
                 var t2 = table2.First(x => x.ID == t1.ID);
                 return new Employee {
                   ID = t1.ID,
                   Name = t1.Name,
                   NickName = t2.NickName
                 };
              }).ToList();
```

If `table2` is sufficiently large (tens of thousands of entries or more) consider (ie. performance measure) building a `Dictionary` or sort the array  to provide quicker lookup by `ID` (in the latter case using the [`BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba2bttb) method with the custom `IComparer` just comparing ids). The cost of setting up this intermediate structure is non-trivial, and modern computers can search a few thousand simple rows very quickly.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Yes it will. There are many approaches to this kind of problem. Personally I would use the simplest possible way, and then modify if it doesn't meet performance requirements.